# How to send pipeline changes(commits) notification to microsoft teams\skype using jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, devops

I want to send pipeline changes(commits) notification to teams channel using Jenkins and notify all what changes have been deployed. I know about the office365 plugin in jenkins but the problem is it only tells the status of pipeline etc pass/fail/stopped.

P.S sending notification to skype would also work. Please help!!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This can be setup directly in teams through the connectors marketplace.

First click on the elipses of a channel you want the information to be posted to.

[image: connectors image]

Search for jenkins and configure

[image: Jenkins configure]

From here you should be able to run through the configuration process supplying details as required.

Comment: I've done this but the problem is it doesn't send the information about the commits that have been deployed on server. How to send more info? @david